# What's up with the sudden appearance of .AppleDouble folders all over my filesystem?

Tags: filesystem, security, directory, apple

Something I have never seen on my Ubuntu machine before now- `.AppleDouble` folders have appeared in *many* different folders all over my filesystem.

It creeped me out- like someone on a Mac was looking through my filesystems? Is there a less paranoid explanation?

Comment: Do you dual boot OS X,or have you added a  mac to the network,or placed files from OS X to a usb/disk and then added those fie to ubuntu?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and add the output of `find / -iname ".appledouble" -type d` to it so that we can see where all those folders are located? That would allow us better conclusions on their purpose. You might have to add the content listing (`ls -a /path/to/folder/`) of some of them later too... Leave me a comment (@ByteCommander) to notify me when you're done. Thank you!